# HTML form submit to JavaScript Form

Tags: php, forms, redirect, submit

I have a HTML form and instead of redirecting to a new page, I would like to display the value that I am trying to retrieve in a javascript alert.
My code retrieves data from a file.

My current code works, but it redirects to user.php in a new page, when user.php is inserted into main.html using the GET method.
this is my code:

```
        <?
        if($_REQUEST['assign'])
            $_SESSION['score'] = my_point_db($_SESSION['sid'], $_REQUEST['assign']);
    ?>

    <form action="user.php" method="get">
        <select name="assign">
                <?
                if($handle=opendir('./assign')){
                while(false!==($file=readdir($handle))){
                if($file!="." && $file!=".."){
                ?><option value=<?=$file?>><?=$file?></option><?
                    }
                }
                closedir($handle);
                }
                ?>
             </select>
        <input type="submit" value="ok">            
    </form>

    <? if($temp){ ?>
    <p>score : <?=$_SESSION['score']?></p>
    <? } ?>
```

Comment: So, when the user clicks on the button, you want to retrieve some information in the server and show it in a alert?
 If yes, it's better use a ajax instead of a form with a submit.

Comment: @VitorLima I haven't learned JavaScript yet, so I don't want to get too far ahead of myself. But I'll keep this in mind, thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it is HTML, you can use iframe code to display your form on the page.

http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_iframe.asp Can be helpfull.

```html
<iframe src="Put the contact form URL here." width="200" height="200"></iframe>
```

Comment: Thanks, I guess that this will have to do for now.